# Vim: Is there a better way to navigate a "select from list" dialog?

Tags: vim, tags

Fairly often, I'll want to use `g]` or `:tsel` to pick one tag out of several. This brings up the little interactive prompt that you may have seen:

```
# pri kind tag      file
1 F C c    MyClass  /path/to/MyClass.java
           bla bla Identifier line A
2 F   c    MyClass  /path/to/MyClass.java
           bla bla Identifier line B
3 F   c    MyClass  /path/to/MyClass.java
           bla bla Identifier line C
Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):
```

If the list is short, this is okay. But often, in my situations, I have a long list, and at the bottom will be:

```
-- More -- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit
```

Is there any way I can choose an item without typing a number?
Perhaps some sort of visual select?

Or maybe dump the output into the `quickfix` list, so I can poke around in there, rather than having the list go away as soon as I make a choice?

Also: can anyone tell me where this kooky little dialog is documented in `:help` ?

**Edit:** I found `:help :tsel` and `:help more-prompt` to have the most info so far. Anyone know others?